# Change cell font colour in a table depending on value - RoR

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a cell in a table which looks like

```
  <td><%= play_result.timestamp.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' ' + play_result.status + ':' + ' ' + '[' + play_result.host + ']' + ' ' + play_result.data  %></td>
```

and I want to write a CSS class that will change the font colour of this cell depending on the value of play_result.status, green where it equals the string 'OK', orange for 'CHANGED', blue for 'SKIPPED' and red for 'FAILED'.

As I'm new to Rails how might I go about this, would I define my CSS class in the view or...?

Comment: i think you're missing the point of table cells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first change your view:

```
<td class="<%= player_result.status %>">
  # your code here
</td>
```

and then, in your css file, make the rules for each status type:

```
.OK {
  color: green;
}
.CHANGED {
  color: orange;
}
.SKIPPED {
  color: blue;
}
.FAILED {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeh sorry for the confusion I meant cell when I said row, I actually want all this info to be in one cell and I want the font in the cell to change depending on the value.